# Laravel 4 relation not working

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4, one-to-many, eloquent

I have the follow migration code (simplified):

Ads Table

```
class CreateAdsTable extends Migration {
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ads', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('authors_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('authors_id')->references('id')->on('authors');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
}
```

Authors Table

```
class CreateAuthorsTable extends Migration {
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('authors', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
}
```

And my models are:

Ad Model

```
class Ad extends \Eloquent {
protected $table = 'ads';

// Ad __hasOne__ Author
public function author() {
    $this->belongsTo('Author');
}
}
```

Author Model

```
class Author extends \Eloquent {

// The database table used by the model
protected $table = 'authors';

// Author __hasMany__ Ads
public function ads() {
    $this->hasMany('Ad');
}
}
```

But when I try to get the author using `Ad::find(1)->author` i receive `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`.

Someone can help me and find the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return it:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Author');
```